# Copy file from Windows to Linux Machine using python

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm a newbie to Python and learning Python on the go. I need to copy a file on Windows 7 to a remote machine running Linux. Is this is doable in Python? If so what module should be used?

I browsed through the internet and heard about paramiko module which is used to establish an ssh connection to the remote server. I tried that but I had problems installing paramiko on my Windows 7 PC.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Or a pointer to install paramiko on Windows 7 should also help.

I get the following error when tried to import paramiko

```
import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
from transport import randpool, SecurityOptions, Transport
File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 37, in <module>
from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 23, in <module>
from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py", line 34, in <module>
from Crypto import Random
File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
import OSRNG
File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py", line 34, in   module>
from Crypto.Random.OSRNG.nt import new
File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py", line 28, in <module>
import winrandom
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider installing samba on the linux server, and then use python's shutil.copyfile().

http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile

http://www.samba.org/

Answer (score 0):

Install anaconda for Python on your windows machine.
This included almost all the python libraries including Pramiko.